# How to check if component is published to a publication target using Tom API in Tridion R 5.3

Tags: api, r5, tom

I am using Tom API in SDL Tridion 5.3. I am getting list of components using `GetItems` method of interface `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS`. I need to get the publication targets from which a component is published.

I can get the similar for pages, as shown in below function:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFolderPublishedPages(string foldername, TDSE tdse, ItemType type, string[] publishedTo = null, string[] notPublishedTo = null)
    {
    Dictionary<string, string> pagelist = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    VirtualFolder fldr = null;
    string componentName = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        fldr = (VirtualFolder)tdse.GetObject(foldername, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeEdit, null, XMLReadFilter.XMLReadNull);
        foreach (Page lObjPage in fldr.GetItems(ItemType.ItemTypePage))
        {
            foreach (string targetURI in publishedTo)
            {
                if (lObjPage.IsPublishedTo(targetURI))
                {
                    foreach (string noTargetURI in notPublishedTo)
                    {
                        if (!lObjPage.IsPublishedTo(noTargetURI))
                        {
                            pagelist.Add(lObjPage.Title, lObjPage.ID);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseComObject(fldr);
    }

    return pagelist;
}
```

Please suggest similarly if I can do a check for component too..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not that it helps you, but FYI: that's not the TOM.NET, that's TOM with a .NET Interop

Comment: Please specify which version of Tridion you are using, and how your code is running (i.e. is this in a template, a custom page, a command line script etc)

Comment: just created a tag for "tom", if you want me to remove it because I have overlooked something, then let me know

Comment: did you get solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try following. this should provide xml with required info, then you need to parse that XML.

so here `yourcomponent` is the component returned by `GetItems` method

```
yourComponent.GetXml(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadPublishInfoDetails);
```

Or

```
yourComponent.GetXml(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadPublishInfo)
```

Or

```
    yourComponent.GetXml(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadPublishInfo | 
XMLReadFilter.XMLReadPublishInfoDetails)
```